# Insert inactive date with elisp function including date arithmetic

Tags: org-mode, time-date

For a capture template I want to insert inactive dates for the upcoming week (without a prompt). In this format (no time component):

`[2020-02-10 Mo]`

I've figured out that I could do something like this
`[%(org-read-date nil nil "Tue")]` which yields `[2020-02-11]`. So it misses the weekday.

I also know about this method
`(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t "+1d"))` but that timestamp is not inactive.

Answer (score 2):

I was close with my last try.
Reading the documentation does help :)

`%(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t "+1d") nil t)`
does the trick. And you can do any date arithmetic in the string part that you would do at the interactive prompt.

Comment: Hey Sebstian, what ist the "%" sign for?

Comment: @breathe_in_breathe_out if you want to execute custom code in a capture template you have to prefix it with the %-sign. There are many possible template expansions and `%(EXP)` is one of them. For a detailed overview see https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html